# Express server doesn't Serve static files on my hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hosting

Locally is everything okey, and my express.js app is serving my js file, but on my hosting there is a problem. I can't get my js file.

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var path = require("path")
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
app.use(express.static('static'))



app.get("/chinczyk", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html") 
})





app.listen();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content=" initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="formlogin">
    <p>Wpisz swój nick:</p>
<input id="nickname" type="text" name="Wpisz swój nick">
<button id="submit" type="submit">OK</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/user.js"></script>
<style>
```

directory of my files on server is like

```
public
static > js > user.js
tmp
app.js
index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
app.use(express.static('static'))
```

use

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

This will handle any issues arising from the script being executed from a different working directory than you might expect. It makes the path to the static folder relative to where the executing script lives, not from where it was started.

Comment: GET https://mlopatkiewicz.pl/chinczyk/js/user.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: that's the wrong URL, the js file is served at https://mlopatkiewicz.pl/js/user.js